# where is the Illuminate Laravel documentation for the join that takes a closure

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-5, subquery

the typical join that looks like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

is well documented in the laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_join) like so:

> $this join(string $table, string $one, string $operator = null, string $two = null, string $type = 'inner', bool $where = false)

However, I have no idea where this kind of join is documented:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')->orOn(...);
        })
        ->get();
```

for example selectSub clearly has a closure in its [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_selectSub):

```
Builder|Builder selectSub(Closure|Builder|string $query, string $as)
```

background: trying to figure the syntax out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747008/how-to-use-inner-joins-with-subqueries-laravel)

Comment: relevant: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on

Answer (score 0):

Go to [`this link`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) and then search the document for `Advanced join clauses` or just scroll down a bit, and you will see that header

Answer (score 0):

if there is a relationship with your tables, you can use `whereHas` method.

```
$stuff = User::whereHas('contacts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $id);
})->get()
```